# Problem using \alert{} in Beamer title with metropolis theme

Tags: beamer, formatting, color, titles, themes

I'm trying to emphasize some words in the title of a beamer document. Ex :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usetheme{Warsaw}%\usetheme{m}%-->problem

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}


  \title{Hello \protect\alert{World}!}
  \author{}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
  \titlepage
  \end{frame}

  \end{document}
```

Which gives the following result :

[image]

But I want to use a theme for the document ( metropolis : see https://github.com/matze/mtheme ). The problem is that errors appear during compilation while using this theme instead of Warsaw theme. The error message is :

```
"! Undefined control sequence.
\beamer@sort #1#2->\long \def \beamer@todo
{#1}\def \beamer@ospec {}\beamer@...
l.12 \end{frame}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Argument of \beamerx@\alert has an extra }.
<inserted text>
..."
```

Is there a way to emphasize some part of the title using this theme (with `\alert{}` or `\textbf` or other environment) ?

Comment: Try with: `\title{Hello \protect\alert{World}!}`

Comment: Indeed, it solves the problem for the example I gave. But the problem remains when using some library of the package tikz. I've updated the minimal working example with the problematic lines, i.e :        \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

Comment: move `\title` after `\begin{document}` and before `\maketitle`.

Comment: @Ignasi You should make those comments into an answer.

Comment: Some other comments: Your code doesn't work here with `Warsaw` either. The `metropolis` theme is now on CTAN and part of TeX Live. It has also been renamed, so that one should use `\usetheme{metropolis}`.

Answer (score 3):

If `\title` is defined after `\begin{document}` but before `\maketitle`, the problem is solved.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{m}%\usetheme{m}%-->problem

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}


\begin{document}
\author{}
\title{Hello \protect\alert{World}!}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Similar solution can be applied with other themes when `TiKZ` is used.

Comment: May I ask why this solves the problem? I don't really understand why that makes the difference.

Comment: @hbaderts, it seems counterintuitive (why should `\title` work differently in the preamble?), but in fact it eliminates the error. Did you try to compile the example? Anyways, I added another answer that circumvents the problem in differently.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `\texorpdfstring` from `hyperref` as the problem is (generally speaking) based on the use of formatting commands while harvesting the meta data. That way you prevent that `\alert` gets ever in touch with pdf-specific procedures. The compiler usually don't likes to see anything but plain text there -- especially with `TikZ` commands it becomes really hard to predict how the compiler digests the material in this case. Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Hello \texorpdfstring{\alert{World}}{World}!}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

If you want to be fancy you may say

```
\let\oldalert\alert
\renewcommand\alert[1]{\texorpdfstring{\oldalert{#1}}{#1}}
```

before `\title`. That way you can continue write `\title{Hello \alert{World}!}`.