# \title after \begin{document}: When to do it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, titles, catcodes

My answer to [Problem using \alert{} in Beamer title with metropolis theme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271766/problem-using-alert-in-beamer-title-with-metropolis-theme/305090#305090) solves an incompatibility problem between `TiKZ` and `\title` with `\protect`-ed contents in `beamer` documents.

Following code fails:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{Hello \protect\alert{World}!} %<- before \begin{document}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

and next one works

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\title{Hello \protect\alert{World}!}%<- after \begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

If the title is `\title{Hello World!}`, there's no problem placing it in preamble.

I found the answer by trial and error and because I remembered some similar answer in TeX.SX. I would like to know why the error happens and why the solution works.

While I was writting this question [Should I place \title, \author, \date in the preamble or after \begin{document}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/92702/should-i-place-title-author-date-in-the-preamble-or-after-begindocument) appeared in my browser. My resume from it  is that it doesn't matter if title commands are declared in preamble or inside the document before `\maketitle` except when it matters. Then my question is when it matters? Only in `beamer`? when using `\protect`? when using `TiKZ`? Is there any general recipe?

Comment: Notice the `babel` answer to the other question.  A summary of that discussion could be: if the title is plain text there is no problem with the placement, if it contains formatting commands, shorthands, etc. then it can be necessary to put the `\title` command in the document body.

Comment: Try `\title{Hello \texorpdfstring{\alert{World}}{World}!}` with the help of `hyperref`.

Comment: I guess the point is that beamer automatically uses the title as `\hypersetup{pdftitle={\inserttitle\ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty\else\ - \insertsubtitle\fi}}`. So if it tries to write the pdf info at the start of the document it encounters problems if control sequences etc. are part of the title. If the title is only defined after the informations are written to the pdf, it does not matter if the title contains something crazy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ultimately the issue here, I think, boils down to two things:

1. If you use `\title` *before* `\begin{document}`, it ends up being incorporated in the PDF properties. After `\begin{document}` and such inclusion is too late.
2. PDF properties are sensitive since they can handle *some* TeX-related macros, but not everything. And, the [`beamer` class](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) does a lot to allow for its overlay specifications and templates. Specifically, `\alert` and everything defined with an overlay specification under `\newcommand`-and-friends will surely cause issues if they end up in the PDF properties.

To examine (1), consider the following minimal examples:

#### `exampleA.tex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Hello world!}% title before \begin{document}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

#### `exampleB.tex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\title{Hello world!}% title after \begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Both yield the same output, but the PDF properties are different. `exampleA.pdf` yields

[image]

while `exampleB.pdf` yields

[image]

This is because `beamer` sets the document option `\beamer@autopdfinfotrue` by default in [`beamer.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamer.cls) and calls

```
\ifbeamer@autopdfinfo%
  \g@addto@macro\beamer@firstminutepatches
  {
    \begingroup
      \let\beamer@saved@hook\pdfstringdefPreHook
      \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
        \let\\=\
        \let\newline=\\%
      }%
      \let\thanks=\@gobble%
      \hypersetup{pdftitle={\inserttitle\ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty\else\ - \insertsubtitle\fi}}
      \global\let\pdfstringdefPreHook\beamer@saved@hook
    \endgroup
  }
\fi%
```

in [`beamerbasetitle.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbasetitle.sty). Note the call to `\hypersetup{pdftitle={...}}` that `\insert`s the `title`.

In support of (2), you can redefine `\alert` to not use an overlay specification nor templates (say, `\def\alert#1{\textcolor{red}{#1}}`) and see that the number of errors during compilation decreases (or it actually compiling).

---

The proposed solution here would be to distinguish between PDF-related content and TeX-related content using `\texorpdfstring{<tex>}{<pdf>}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usepackage{tikz}% With or without tikz
\title{Hello \texorpdfstring{\protect\alert{world}}{world}!}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Of course, you can also go overboard and use

```
\let\oldalert\alert% Store \alert in \oldalert
\let\alert\relax% Make \alert a null-op
\AtBeginDocument{\let\alert\oldalert}% Restore \alert at \begin{document}
```

or something similar for anything that may be problematic for inclusion in the PDF properties.